# Create column values based on multiple conditions in other columns

Tags: pandas

having a dataframe, df, with some columns describing some units and their output in a given bin as exemplified below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bin_dir' : pd.cut(np.rad2deg(np.random.vonmises(np.pi,0.03,100)) % 360,np.arange(0,365,5)),
                   'Unit' : np.tile(np.arange(1,11),10),
                   'value' : np.random.randn(100)*1000+3600})
```

I now wants to create a column col1 which has the value 1 when unit is 1,3,5 and bin_dir is (350,355], (355,360], (0,5], (5,10] and 2 when the units are 2,4,9 and dir_bin is (350,355], (355,360], (0,5], (5,10]

How can one do that? in dplyr I can use mutate with nested `ifelse` statements.
It would be nice if the solution could be incorporated in a chained command :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use nested [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

In [50]: bins = re.findall(r'\(.*?\]', '(350, 355], (355, 360], (0, 5], (5, 10]')
    ...: bin_mask = df.bin_dir.isin(bins)
    ...: unit_mask1 = df.Unit.isin([1,3,5])
    ...: unit_mask2 = df.Unit.isin([2,4,9])
    ...:

In [51]: df.assign(col1=
    ...:     np.where(bin_mask & unit_mask1,
    ...:              1,
    ...:              np.where(bin_mask & unit_mask2, 2, np.nan)
    ...:     )
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[51]:
    Unit     bin_dir        value  col1
0      1  (195, 200]  1228.056261   NaN
1      2  (125, 130]  3246.052662   NaN
2      3  (150, 155]  3128.356490   NaN
3      4  (215, 220]  2900.812099   NaN
4      5  (110, 115]  4324.152904   NaN
5      6  (150, 155]  4783.110204   NaN
6      7  (240, 245]  4810.120258   NaN
7      8  (210, 215]  4307.576911   NaN
8      9    (15, 20]  3043.099987   NaN
9     10      (0, 5]  4633.435048   NaN
10     1  (145, 150]  3401.690163   NaN
11     2  (320, 325]  4224.314088   NaN
12     3  (350, 355]  4037.081806   1.0
13     4  (295, 300]  3096.652374   NaN
14     5  (235, 240]  4738.227922   NaN
15     6  (235, 240]  1973.561204   NaN
16     7  (270, 275]  3500.619163   NaN
17     8    (45, 50]  4234.621801   NaN
18     9  (255, 260]  4267.575087   NaN
19    10  (320, 325]  3031.733130   NaN
20     1  (235, 240]  3137.832272   NaN
21     2  (330, 335]  4113.654195   NaN
22     3  (265, 270]  3060.886390   NaN
23     4  (290, 295]  2836.105371   NaN
24     5  (255, 260]  2756.894839   NaN
..   ...         ...          ...   ...
75     6  (325, 330]  2471.775169   NaN
76     7    (70, 75]  4463.964881   NaN
77     8  (110, 115]  5681.124294   NaN
78     9  (135, 140]  2500.650717   NaN
79    10  (225, 230]  2936.364153   NaN
80     1  (280, 285]  1138.591459   NaN
81     2  (250, 255]  3121.142300   NaN
82     3  (150, 155]  2991.257906   NaN
83     4  (160, 165]  3078.156743   NaN
84     5  (130, 135]  4335.076559   NaN
85     6    (85, 90]  4970.471290   NaN
86     7  (335, 340]  3207.906304   NaN
87     8  (350, 355]  3605.474926   NaN
88     9  (125, 130]  4922.963220   NaN
89    10    (60, 65]  3121.061944   NaN
90     1  (105, 110]  3092.191627   NaN
91     2      (0, 5]  3693.602055   2.0
92     3  (195, 200]  2291.508096   NaN
93     4    (40, 45]  4628.409801   NaN
94     5  (215, 220]  3327.321452   NaN
95     6  (110, 115]  4347.471046   NaN
96     7  (110, 115]  4494.707840   NaN
97     8  (110, 115]  3545.460851   NaN
98     9    (55, 60]  2831.042251   NaN
99    10    (30, 35]  3705.225870   NaN

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Of course you can do this without precomputed masks:

```
In [52]: df.assign(col1=
    ...:     np.where(df.bin_dir.isin(bins) & df.Unit.isin([1,3,5]),
    ...:              1,
    ...:              np.where(df.bin_dir.isin(bins) & df.Unit.isin([2,4,9]),
    ...:                       2,
    ...:                       np.nan
    ...:              )
    ...:     )
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[52]:
    Unit     bin_dir        value  col1
0      1  (195, 200]  1228.056261   NaN
1      2  (125, 130]  3246.052662   NaN
2      3  (150, 155]  3128.356490   NaN
3      4  (215, 220]  2900.812099   NaN
4      5  (110, 115]  4324.152904   NaN
5      6  (150, 155]  4783.110204   NaN
6      7  (240, 245]  4810.120258   NaN
7      8  (210, 215]  4307.576911   NaN
8      9    (15, 20]  3043.099987   NaN
9     10      (0, 5]  4633.435048   NaN
10     1  (145, 150]  3401.690163   NaN
11     2  (320, 325]  4224.314088   NaN
12     3  (350, 355]  4037.081806   1.0
13     4  (295, 300]  3096.652374   NaN
14     5  (235, 240]  4738.227922   NaN
15     6  (235, 240]  1973.561204   NaN
16     7  (270, 275]  3500.619163   NaN
17     8    (45, 50]  4234.621801   NaN
18     9  (255, 260]  4267.575087   NaN
19    10  (320, 325]  3031.733130   NaN
20     1  (235, 240]  3137.832272   NaN
21     2  (330, 335]  4113.654195   NaN
22     3  (265, 270]  3060.886390   NaN
23     4  (290, 295]  2836.105371   NaN
24     5  (255, 260]  2756.894839   NaN
..   ...         ...          ...   ...
75     6  (325, 330]  2471.775169   NaN
76     7    (70, 75]  4463.964881   NaN
77     8  (110, 115]  5681.124294   NaN
78     9  (135, 140]  2500.650717   NaN
79    10  (225, 230]  2936.364153   NaN
80     1  (280, 285]  1138.591459   NaN
81     2  (250, 255]  3121.142300   NaN
82     3  (150, 155]  2991.257906   NaN
83     4  (160, 165]  3078.156743   NaN
84     5  (130, 135]  4335.076559   NaN
85     6    (85, 90]  4970.471290   NaN
86     7  (335, 340]  3207.906304   NaN
87     8  (350, 355]  3605.474926   NaN
88     9  (125, 130]  4922.963220   NaN
89    10    (60, 65]  3121.061944   NaN
90     1  (105, 110]  3092.191627   NaN
91     2      (0, 5]  3693.602055   2.0
92     3  (195, 200]  2291.508096   NaN
93     4    (40, 45]  4628.409801   NaN
94     5  (215, 220]  3327.321452   NaN
95     6  (110, 115]  4347.471046   NaN
96     7  (110, 115]  4494.707840   NaN
97     8  (110, 115]  3545.460851   NaN
98     9    (55, 60]  2831.042251   NaN
99    10    (30, 35]  3705.225870   NaN

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

but it'll be slower and it looks bit cumbersome

Comment: Nice one using np.where + assign. I won't instinctively think of using it at first, I would probably use a simple list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension :

```
bin_filt = ['(350, 355]', '(355, 360]', '(0, 5]', '(5, 10]']
# Creates a column 'col1'
df['col1'] = [1 for i in range(df.shape[0]) if df['Unit'][i] in [1, 3, 5] and df['bin_dir'][i] in bin_filt else 0]
# Creates a column 'col2'
df['col2'] = [2 for i in range(df.shape[0]) if df['Unit'][i] in [2, 4, 9] and df['bin_dir'][i] in bin_filt else 0]
# You can replace the 'else' statement a t the end of the list comprehension to put the value you want instead
```

Comment: It gives me `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: are values of `df['bin_dir']` strings ?

Comment: sure, it's of a `category` dtype, which is `string` under the hood

Comment: now it gives: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (it doesn't like `else`)... You can easily test it yourself as OP has provided a code which generates DF

Comment: @MaxU : Thanks for your feedbacks